# Calculate the Gamma function Γ(2.7)

Tags: numerical-methods, gamma-function

> \begin{align}
> \displaystyle Γ(2.7) &= \int_{0}^{∞} x^{(2.7-1)} \cdot e^{(-x)} dx  \\[7pt]
> Γ(2.7)               &= 1.54968 
> \end{align}

I got this answer online, but I do not know how to get it. Would you please explain how to get the value of this gamma function?

Comment: Start with integration by parts. Then go about with the standard procedure for an improper integral.

Comment: @Gilles, it is best not to add the `[self-study]` tag for the OP. Instead, ask them to add it themselves & read its wiki. (If you like you can find suggested text [here](http://meta.stats.stackexchange.com/a/2486/7290).) That way there is a better chance they will be familiar w/ our policies, & if they don't add the tag, we can close the thread.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @gung, thanks. I will remember that in the future.

Comment: R shows gamma(2.7) is 1.544686, Wolfram Alpha agrees the integral is 1.54469

Comment: @Lauren Numerical analysts have found that a far better technique is to use the functional relationship $\Gamma(n) = \Gamma(n+1)/n$ repeatedly until $n+1$ is so large that [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) to $\Gamma(n+1)$ is sufficiently accurate.  Very few of these steps are needed: using five terms in the asymptotic series and stopping as soon as $n+1 \ge 6$ gives ten decimal digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

See this article on the Gamma function from the Digital Library of Mathematical Functions.  There's no simple way to compute values of the Gamma function by hand, but there are a number of ways to implement this in software and lots of software is already written for this task.

http://dlmf.nist.gov/5

Comment: can i use the calculator (TI -83 PLUS)  to get the answer

Comment: Your TI-83 PLUS probably can't do this.  However, it's easy to evaluate using Wolfram Alpha.  http://www.wolframalpha.com/